# How to enable an federated storage engine in the Debian MySQL package?

Tags: debian, apt, mysql

How would I enable an extra (in this case `FEDERATED`) storage engine in the `mysql-server-5.1` package from Debian?

I've installed `mysql-server-5.1` via apt-get. But the `SHOW ENGINES` shows that federated is not enabled.

```
mysql> show engines;
+------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine     | Support | Comment                                                        | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| InnoDB     | YES     | Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys     | YES          | YES  | YES        |
| MRG_MYISAM | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                          | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| BLACKHOLE  | YES     | /dev/null storage engine (anything you write to it disappears) | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| CSV        | YES     | CSV storage engine                                             | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MEMORY     | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables      | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| FEDERATED  | NO      | Federated MySQL storage engine                                 | NULL         | NULL | NULL       |
| ARCHIVE    | YES     | Archive storage engine                                         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MyISAM     | DEFAULT | Default engine as of MySQL 3.23 with great performance         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
+------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: It seems it was discused here: http://serverfault.com/q/236070/104326

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beginning with MySQL 5.1.26, the FEDERATED storage engine is not enabled by default in the running server; to enable FEDERATED, you must start the MySQL server binary using the `--federated` option.

Or edit your `/etc/my.cnf` global server configuration file and under `[mysqld]` stanza section, add the line:

```
federated
```

The mysqld service has to be restarted to get the federated engine enabled and this will be enabled by default for every instance/restart of mysql service.